# RainLoop+tomav/docker-mailserver: Cannot connect to server from RainLoop Webmail client

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mail-server

To start off, I followed this guide to the letter: https://www.davd.eu/byecloud-building-a-mailserver-with-modern-webmail/

I am attempting to create a mailserver for my server, but I thought I'd test the above implementation locally first. Make sure I can get everything up and running at least so I can see what I should be expecting before trying it on the server. Here's what I did:

1. Added "127.0.0.1 mail.fancydomain.tld" to "/etc/hosts" (I wanted to start by using mail.fancydomain.tld rather than my actual domain that the mailserver will be on to minimize any changing while following the guide)
2. I created this "docker-compose.yml":

   ```
      version: "3"

       services:
         rainloop:
           image: hardware/rainloop
           links:
             - mail
           volumes:
             - ./data/rainloop:/rainloop/data

         mail:
           image: tvial/docker-mailserver:latest
           restart: always
           hostname: mail
           domainname: fancydomain.tld
           container_name: mail
           ports:
             - "25:25"
             - "143:143"
             - "587:587"
             - "993:993"
             - "4190:4190"
           volumes:
             - ./data/mail/data:/var/mail
             - ./data/mail/state:/var/mail-state
             - ./mail/config:/tmp/docker-mailserver/
             - ./data/entry/acme/acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/sites/mail.fancydomain.tld:/tmp/ssl:ro
           environment:
             - ENABLE_SPAMASSASSIN=1
             - ENABLE_CLAMAV=1
             - ENABLE_FAIL2BAN=1
             - ENABLE_POSTGREY=1
             - ONE_DIR=1
             - DMS_DEBUG=0
             - ENABLE_MANAGESIEVE=1
           cap_add:
             - NET_ADMIN

         entry:
           image: abiosoft/caddy:0.10.4
           restart: always
           privileged: true
           links:
             - rainloop
           ports:
             - "80:80"
             - "443:443"
           volumes:
             - ./entry/Caddyfile:/etc/Caddyfile
             - ./data/entry:/root/.caddy
   ```

   There is a small difference between this "docker-compose.yml" and the one provided by the site previously mentioned. All I did was remove the environment variables prefixed with "SSL_" as instructed by the guide for people who are just running it locally.
3. I created a directory in the current working directory called "entry" and created a "Caddyfile" with these contents:

   ```
      http://mail.fancydomain.tld {
           proxy / rainloop:8888 {
               transparent
           }
       }
   ```

   Again, just a small difference from the one provided on the site. I prefixed the domain with "http://" for the same reason as step 2.
4. I successfully started the container with `docker-compose up -d`
5. I ran: `curl -o setup.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tomav/docker-mailserver/master/setup.sh; chmod a+x ./setup.sh` to obtain the setup script.
6. I ran: `./setup.sh email add webmaster@fancydomain.tld fancypassword` with those exact credentials, again to minimizes changes to keep track of.
7. I setup the DKIM records by running `./setup.sh config dkim` but I did not proceed further with these records... As I'm not sure what to do with these locally.
8. I successfully connected to the RainLoop Webmail client via, "http://mail.fancydomain.tld/" and proceeded to "http://mail.fancydomain.tld/?admin" to login with the credentials: Login=admin Password=12345
9. I proceeded to "Domains" > "Add Domain" and used filled out the form as so:

   ```
   Name: fancydomain.tld
       IMAP
         Server: mail
         Port: 143
         Secure: STARTTLS
       SMTP
         Server: mail
         Port: 587
         Secure: STARTTLS
         Use short login: Checked
         Use authentication: Checked
       SIEVE
         Allow sieve scripts: Checked
         Server: mail
         Port: 4190
         Secure: STARTTLS
   ```
10. From here I returned to "http://mail.fancydomain.tld" and tried to login to the Webmail client with this login: Login=webmaster@fancydomain.tld Password=fancypassword

This is where I get the error: "Can't connect to server"

I am not sure where to go from here. I don't know how to troubleshoot at all. Can I please get some help on what I should be doing to troubleshoot and figure out where the error is?

Thank you!

07/01/18 Update: So... I added "127.0.0.1 mail" into "/etc/hosts" and it worked! RainLoop can now connect to my mailserver! This brings up a new question though. For step 9, instead of "mail" for the three "Server" fields, I tried, "mail.fancydomain.tld" and according to the test, the connection is being refused. Why would the connection be refused for the full domain but not the short domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this one it to make sure both containers, RainLoop and Mail, share a bridged network. Then all the configurations can stay the same.